# Terraform Interpolation error : bad substitution

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, puppet, aws-cloudformation, terraform

I am trying to set up the puppet master-slave setup with terraform on AWS.
I have 2 EC2 instance one is master and second is slave.

I have written script as setup.tf

```
provider "aws"{
region="us-east-1"
access_key="XXXX"
secret_key="XXXX"
}

resource "aws_security_group" "default"{
        name="terraform-sg"
        description="Created by terraform"

ingress {
from_port = 0
to_port = 0
protocol = "-1"
cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
}
egress{
from_port = 0
to_port = 65535
protocol = "tcp"
cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
     }

}

resource "aws_instance" "puppet_master"{

connection={
user="ubuntu"
key_file="/home/vaibhav/Downloads/puppet_elk.pem"
}

instance_type="t2.micro"

ami="ami-fce3c696"
key_name = "puppet_elk"
security_groups= ["${aws_security_group.default.name}"]
tags{
Name="master"
}

provisioner "file" {
source = "./scripts/puppet-master.sh"
destination = "~/puppet-master.sh"
}

provisioner "remote-exec" {
inline = [
"chmod +x ~/puppet-master.sh",
"~/puppet-master.sh puppet"
  ]
    }
}

resource "aws_instance" "puppet_node"{

depends_on = ["aws_instance.puppet_master"]

connection={
user="ubuntu"
key_file="/home/vaibhav/Downloads/puppet_elk.pem"
}

instance_type="t2.micro"

ami="ami-fce3c696"
key_name = "puppet_elk"
security_groups= ["${aws_security_group.default.name}"]
tags{
Name="node"
}

provisioner "file" {
source = "./scripts/puppet-node.sh"
destination = "~/puppet-node.sh"
}

provisioner "remote-exec" {
inline = [
"chmod +x ~/puppet-node.sh",
"~/puppet-node.sh node1"
  ]
    }
```

Script I am using for installing the puppet master and slave is :

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
echo "No hostname supplied"
exit
fi
env=$1
echo $env
hostname=`hostname`
myipaddress=$(ifconfig eth0 | awk '/inet addr/{print substr($2,6)}')
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo wget http://apt.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-trusty.deb
sudo dpkg -i puppetlabs-release-trusty.deb
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get -y install puppetmaster
sudo sed -i "s/$hostname/$env/g" /etc/hostname
sudo sed -i "s/no/yes/g" /etc/default/puppetmaster
sudo echo "127.0.0.1 puppet.example.net puppet" >> /etc/hosts
sudo echo "$myipaddress puppet.example.net puppet" >> /etc/hosts

sudo reboot
```

For Slave :

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
echo "No hostname supplied"
exit
fi
env=$1
echo $env
hostname=`hostname`
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo wget http://apt.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-trusty.deb
sudo dpkg -i puppetlabs-release-trusty.deb
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo pt-get -y install puppet
sudo ed -i "s/$hostname/$env/g" /etc/hostname
sudo sed -i "s/no/yes/g" /etc/default/puppet
# replace IP with the variable

#masterip=${aws_instance.puppet-node.private_ip}
sudo echo "${aws_instance.puppet_master.private_ip} puppet.example.net puppet" >> /etc/hosts
sudo echo "${aws_instance.puppet_master.private_ip} puppet" >> /etc/hosts
sudo puppet agent --enable
sudo puppet agent --waitforcert 60
sudo reboot
```

When I run this script i get the error for interpolation in the slave shell script :

{aws_instance.puppet_master.private_ip} : bad interpolation

I want to substitute the master private Ip in place of this interpolation string as to setup the master slave in puppet I need master IP.

Is there any work around for this ?

Comment: i'm not sure the file provisioner interpolates variables that way. Why not just use the template provisioner (https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/template/) and pass the template as user_data to the aws instance.

Comment: @ptierno I cant do that reason behind is I have to sign the node certificates on master once node is started and that is not possible in case of passing the user_data to the instance.Anyways I am looking for ELK stack puppet manifest, It is highly appreciable if you provide any help in this. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can not use terraform vars directly in shell file. They way to go about this is use %s in shell code, and then pass the var directly using $format():

For eg:

```
!/bin/bash
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
echo "No hostname supplied"
exit
fi
env=$1
echo $env
hostname=`hostname`
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo wget http://apt.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-trusty.deb
sudo dpkg -i puppetlabs-release-trusty.deb
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo pt-get -y install puppet
sudo ed -i "s/$hostname/$env/g" /etc/hostname
sudo sed -i "s/no/yes/g" /etc/default/puppet
# replace IP with the variable

#masterip=${aws_instance.puppet-node.private_ip}
sudo echo "%s" >> /etc/hosts
sudo echo "%s puppet" >> /etc/hosts
sudo puppet agent --enable
sudo puppet agent --waitforcert 60
sudo reboot
```

and then pass the value with something like this:

```
${format(file("path/to/file.json"), "${aws_instance.puppet_master.private_ip}","${aws_instance.puppet_master.private_ip}")}
```

Comment: Thank for the time, I get a work around for this problem, I modify the script to accept two parameters and then using the inline in remote exec I passed the interpolation script and it works well.